# Threads and waiting for data

Tags: c, multithreading, centos, pthreads

new here ;)
I've started working with threads on CentOS and I need some help about specific problem with threads since I'm beginner in this. 
I have 2 arrays - input and output. They have the same size N. Also I have TNO threads. Each thread is doing the same operation on N/TNO chunk of the input data and writing the output to a N/TNO part of the output array. Also, TNO represents a number of data sources (each source one thread). Main program receives the data from some source continuously and there will be occurrences when there will be more data on one source than on another. Here is sort of pseudo code of operation which I want to implement:

```
void *thread_function(void *argument){
while(1){
  wait for input data
  //DO SOMETHING
  send signal to main that thread work is done
  if(data_end)
    break

  }
}
main(){
initialization of variables
thread create
while(input_data){
  read input data
  send signal to threads that there is input data
  wait for all threads to finish their work
  write output data
  }
thread join
}
```

I was researching a lot but need some help about those signals to threads and from threads to the main. I don't want to use global variables except for input and output. Also, if one of the threads have no more data to process I also don't need to proceed to DO SOMETHING part of the thread function.
My main problem is how to implement those waits and what to do when I skip DO SOMETHING (no more data for that thread) part.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`. BTW, what are "TNO threads"? It's not standard terminology that I have come across and a quick google did not enlighten me.

Comment: "TNO represents a number of data sources (each source one thread)." as written on problem explanation. I was looking before at functions suggested by you but don't know how to implement them along with mutexes both in threads function and main function.

Comment: It's too hard to write a good answer, I tried ... a good answer relies on your understanding of safely sharing state, as well as an understanding of primitives already mentioned. It might be a good idea to try, it might be easier to correct an attempt than it is to explain it from the very beginning.